# Is modifying a database on compressed ZFS slow?

Tags: filesystems, performance, zfs, compression

Is modifying (mainly inserting new rows into tables with many indexes) a (PostgreSQL) database on a compressed ZFS slow (compared to an uncompressed ZFS)?

I used a slow HDD backed by SSDs. Ubuntu Linux 21 on AWS.

Comment: I'm afraid it depends on your definition of "slow". Also, you say have a "slow" HDD - does this mean you already consider this to be the bottleneck? Unfortunately, without some hard numbers to explain the situation (which I wouldn't know how to determine, admittedly), you question is almost impossible to answer ...

Comment: @AdminBee Definition of slow is "compared to an uncompressed ZFS".

Comment: @AdminBee I ask about the case when the current data does fit inside the SSD cache.